# How override data in aws glue?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

Cosider a code:

```
val inputTable = glueContext
  .getCatalogSource(database = "my_db", tableName = "my_table)
  .getDynamicFrame()

glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(
  connectionType = "s3",
  options = JsonOptions(Map("path" -> "s3://my_out_path")),
  format = "orc", transformationContext = ""
).writeDynamicFrame(inputTable)
```

When I run this code twice new `orc` files added to old ones in  `"s3://my_out_path"`. Is there a way to overwrite always override path?

**Note**

The writting data have no partition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the spark to overwrite the content. You can still read your data with Glue methods, but then change it to a spark dataframe and overwrite the files:

```
datasink = DynamicFrame.toDF(inputTable)
datasink.write.\
            format("orc").\
            mode("overwrite").\
            save("s3://my_out_path")
```